# How to click links in google sheet from keyboard?

Tags: google-sheets

I have multiple links in google sheet, I want to open each link in new tab, How I can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply select the cell and press **Alt + Enter**

Answer (score 1):

Click on the cell containing link and a small popup will appear and then right click and select "open link on a new Tab".

or

Click on the cell containing the link and then **Alt + Enter** to open in a new Tab.